# DAX - Advanced Product Grouping/Segmentation Question

Tags: dax, tabular

I created an SSAS Tabular model using the AdventureWorksDW database.

I used the post below to help me build the report.

https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2014/02/applied-basket-analysis-in-power-pivot-using-dax/

```
Sold in same Order:=
CALCULATE (
COUNTROWS ( 'Internet Sales' ),
CALCULATETABLE ( 
SUMMARIZE ( 
'Internet Sales',
'Internet Sales'[SalesOrderNumber]
),
ALL ( 'Product' ) ,
USERELATIONSHIP( 'Internet Sales'[ProductKey],FilteredProduct[ProductKey])
)
)
```

I have validated that the results from the formula are correct.  There are 1,381 orders with the Touring Tire Tube sold and shows me how many orders were sold with the other items (e.g. 170 out of the 1,381 orders also included product key 214 - Sport-100 Helmet, Red).

[image]
**Here is where I'm having an issue.**  I would like to summarize my data by showing how many of the orders only included my filtered items vs. orders sold with other products.  This has to be dynamic since users can select any products...  The end result should look like this:

[image]

I'm new to DAX and have struggled with this for a few hours.  Thanks for your help.

Here is the table relationship:

[image]

Comment: what if the viewer of the report selects multiple products in his filter (e.g. 3)? would you expect to see only orders where all 3 products were bought together? Would you like to see orders where only those products but not necessarily all of them were bought?

Comment: If the viewer selects 3 products , I’d expect to see orders in which those products were bought but not necessarily together so the latter situation you mentioned.. thanks!

Comment: Can you post your table relationship view and a sample of your sales table?

Comment: Added the table relationship to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this DAX should work on the example dataset from my blog:

```
Orders with only the filtered products = 
--VAR vFilteredProducts = VALUES('Filtered Product'[ProductKey])
VAR vFilteredProducts = FILTER('Filtered Product', [ProductKey] = 530 || [ProductKey] = 541)
VAR vCountFilteredProducts = COUNTROWS(vFilteredProducts)
VAR vSales = CALCULATETABLE('Internet Sales',  -- get the Sales for the filtered Products
    vFilteredProducts,
    USERELATIONSHIP('Filtered Product'[ProductKey], 'Internet Sales'[ProductKey]), 
    ALL('Product'))
VAR vOrders = SUMMARIZE( -- Summarize the filtered product sales by Sales Order Number
    vSales, 
    [Sales Order Number],
    -- calucate the distinct filtered products in the filtered orders
    "CountFilteredProductsInOrder", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Internet Sales'[ProductKey])),
    -- calculate the all distinct products for the filtered orders 
    "CountTotalProductsInOrder", CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Internet Sales'[ProductKey]), 
                ALLEXCEPT('Internet Sales', 'Internet Sales'[Sales Order Number]))
    )
RETURN COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        vOrders, 
        -- the total product count has to match the filtered product count --> no other products except filtered ones in order
        [CountFilteredProductsInOrder] = [CountTotalProductsInOrder]
    )
)
```

To get the orders where also other products except the filtered ones were sold, imply change the last FILTER() from '=' to '<'

Comment: I have learned an immense amount by studying your query.  I was expecting to see a dynamic segmentation approach vs. calculated measures.  Something similar to this https://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/. I have tried dozens of ways to incorporate the dynamic segmentation logic with no success.  The **reason why** I was looking for segmentation is because I wanted to add quantity and sales.  I realize I didn't add quantity or sales but it was only in hopes of keeping the post brief.  Do you think it is possible to use a dynamic segmentation approach? Thanks!!

Comment: so you want to run a segmentation on top of the calculation above?
Theoretically this should be possible as it should work on every measure. Performance has to be tested though
I'd recommend to raise a new question for this purpose

Comment: Here is the link to the new post.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated.  Thanks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659128/dax-segment-calculated-measures